# Issue with getline from file

Tags: c++, text-files, getline

I am trying to read lines from a .txt file and print them out using `std::cout`. My code is posted below, but currently is not passing any lines to the vector during the while loop. Where did I go wrong?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::ifstream input("input1.txt");//(argv[1]);
    if (!input.good()) {
        cerr << "Can not open the grades file "; //<< argv[1] << "\n";
        return 1; 
    }

    std::vector<string> art;
    string x;                    // Input variable
    // Read the scores, appending each to the end of the vector
    cout << "Start While:"; //For Debugging Purposes
    while (getline(input, x)) { 
        art.push_back(x);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<art.size(); i++) {
        cout << art[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there any lines in the file? The code looks fine to me.

Comment: Verified OK w/ VS2013.4

Comment: The only thing I see odd about this code is the smattering of mixed use, and non-use, of qualified `std` namespace (you should prefer the "use" side, btw). the code otherwise looks reasonable and should function provided `input` is opened on a file containing data lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Xcode was just being difficult. After moving a few files around and running it in the compiler it worked.